# Windows 7 does not boot with 2nd SATA disk attached

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot

My main OS is Ubuntu on a 256GB SSD with the following partitions (set up by the Ubuntu installer):

- primary

  - 30GB
- extended

  - 30GB
  - 30GB
  - 8GB (swap)
  - 156GB

The partition system is msdos rather than GPT.

I've just added a second 128GB SSD for the purpose of installing **Windows 7 Home**, and found (after much teeth-gnashing) that the install would crash with a 0x0000225 error whenever my linux disk was plugged in. So I unplugged it just to get Windows installed.

Now I really want to figure out why Windows **will not boot at all** when my Linux disk is plugged in, failing with a singularly unhelpful and generic error ("Windows could not start... Repair?... Windows could not start... Repair? ..." forever.)

I have found [one not-particularly-confidence-inspiring post](http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/270291-windows-7-wont-boot-two-disks.html#post2225072) suggesting that Windows is having difficulty with the number of logical partitions on the Linux disk, and that the solution is to convert those to primary partitions, but I am not keen to do that. I'm also surprised to have this problem at all, having dual-booted many times in the past.

My system is homebuilt but pretty generic: Asus P8H61-I Motherboard,  i7-2600K.

Can anyone suggest a possible culprit, or workaround. I've looked in my BIOS for any compatibility options I might try but couldn't see anything obvious.

**Update**: There appears to be an issue (discussed [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fd6fa936-5f83-487b-864a-47b6030382fb/extended-partition-on-old-mbr-hdd-makes-windows-7-uefi-boot-fail?forum=w7itproinstall)) with Windows 7 failing to boot when there's an extended partition on another mbr-formatted disk. So I suspect this is my problem.

Comment: Did you change the BIOS temporary boot priority when you wanted to boot into Windows 7 ?

Comment: @whs yes I've tried this (and every one combination of boot priority I can think of). It's very perplexing.

Comment: What kind of motherboard do you have? I had similar problem with my Ubuntu/Mint/Windows7 combination but finally I have learned how to boot PC from specific hard drive though the BIOS ;-). It might be the way.

Answer (score 1):

Since this *appears* to be a [bug with Windows 7 for which there does not seem to be a fix](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fd6fa936-5f83-487b-864a-47b6030382fb/extended-partition-on-old-mbr-hdd-makes-windows-7-uefi-boot-fail?forum=w7itproinstall), I ended up working around the problem by "fixing" my Linux disk by converting the partition table from MBR to GPT using [gdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) and then un-borking my Grub2 install via an Ubuntu live CD and [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).